# tensorflow tf.disable_eager_execution() not working?

Tags: tensorflow

Here are the commands and outputs:

```
>>> tf.enable_eager_execution()
>>> tf.executing_eagerly()
True
>>> tf.disable_eager_execution()
>>> tf.executing_eagerly()
True
>>>
```

Why disable_eager_execution is not working?